# Can't connect via SOAP v1

Tags: soap

I am trying to point a php SoapClient at http://me.com/api/?wdsl and when I call $soap->login(), I get:

"PHP Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Sender] DTD are not supported by SOAP in ..."

I have tried adding options to the SoapClient constructor but nothing works. Any ideas?  My code is as follows:

```
<?php

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");  

require_once('../../../../Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$mageUrl    = 'http://me.com/api.php?type=soap&wsdl=1';
$mageUser   = 'XXXXX';
$mageApiKey = 'XXXXX';

$soap = new SoapClient($mageUrl,
        array( 'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2, 'trace'=>1,     'user_agent'=>'SoapMasterFlex',
        'login' => 'XXXXX', 'password'=>'XXXXX',
'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => true
));

var_dump($soap);

echo $soap->__getLastResponse();

try {
$sessionID = $soap->login($mageUser, $mageApiKey);
}
catch (SoapFault $soapFault) {
    var_dump($soapFault);
    echo "Request :<br>", htmlentities($soap->__getLastRequest()), "<br>";
    echo "Response :<br>", htmlentities($soap->__getLastResponse()), "<br>";
}
```

Maybe someone could try making something like this work on their install?

Comment: Also, I have added that mage user and mage api key via the web services toolbar FWIW.

Comment: Also, this might help:  For me, this code throws an exception upon $soap->login(), then after complaining about the DTD it appears to return the magento admin login screen in HTML.  I'm fairly certain that the issue is that SOAP wants XML output but that login call is outputting HTML but I don't know how to get it to output anything else.

Answer (score 2):

For me your script worked both with `http://www.domain.tld/api/soap/?wsdl` and `http://www.domain.tld/api/?wsdl`. The URL containing `api.php` return the code for the homepage.

Do you get an XML response if you call one of the two mentioned URLs in your web browser? Because you should.

Comment: I get a reasonable XML response when I access: http://www.domain.tld/api/?wsdl

Comment: I also get a reasonable XML response when I access: www.domain.tld/api.php?type=soap&wsdl=1

Comment: But FYI, I don't get reasonable access when I point my script at those, only a browser.

Comment: what response do you get when you run my code?

Comment: The output of your code:
`class SoapClient#51 (6) { public $_login => string(10) "ImportTest" public $_password => string(6) "123123" public $trace => int(1) public $_user_agent => string(14) "SoapMasterFlex" public $_soap_version => int(2) public $sdl => resource(195) of type (Unknown) }`

Comment: Does it throw any exceptions for you?

Comment: Not with the two URLs mentioned above. If I had got exceptions, I would have mentioned them.